# Kotlin synthetic id collision bug

Tags: android, kotlin

I have fragment and inside fragment RecyclerView with Points and static view with PointsDetail.

[image]

Adaper listener:

```
      holder.container.setOnClickListener {
            adapterListener.onItemClick(tmsLightPoint)
      }

      interface OnClickListener {
            fun onItemClick(place: TmsLightPlace)
      }
```

Item list xml element ( list xml ):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addressTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Wrocław (ul. Testowa 44, 00-007 Polska)" />
```

But also on details view I'm displaying address from this point so again I have ( static details view xml ):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressTv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameTv"
            tools:text="Wrocław (ul. Testowa 44, 00-007 Polska)" />
```

After clicking on the list item:

```
 override fun onItemClick(place: TmsLightPlace) {
        LogMgr.v(TAG, "onItemClick() $place")
        addressTv?.text = place.address
 }
```

**Address is changing but not in my details view but in list address first item.**

In fragment I have only one synthetic import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_points.*
```

**It is a BUG or FEATURE ? : )**

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is expected. The same would happen if you called `view.findViewById(R.id.addressTv)` (which the synthetic property does under the hood) because it traversed the view hierarchy depth-first and since the `RecyclerView` comes first, the first item with this ID found is the list item.

You have two possibilities

**Change the ID of one of the views**

or

**Specify a different parent than the fragment itself** to look for the view, e.g. `detailsLayout.addressTv?.text = place.address`. You'll need the following imports for that:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_points.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_points.view.*
```

In this scenario, the view will not be cached so you'll have a minimal performance penalty.